# SAT word problem

Tags: education

Set S consists of all positive multiples of 5 that are less than 100, and set T consists of all positive multiples of 10 that are less than 100. The median of the numbers in set T is how much greater than the median of the numbers in set S?

Comment: They are both 50. Here I'm assuming when you say less than 100 you mean strictly less than 100.

Comment: Do you know what a median is? Can you find the median of $\{1, 2, 3\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of multiples of $5$ which are less than $100$ is $\frac{95}{5}=19$.  So, the median is the $\frac{19+1}{2}$-th term, which is $50$.

The number of multiples of $10$ which are less than $100$ is $\frac{90}{10} = 9$.  By the same process, the median is $50$.

Therefore, the difference is $0$.

Comment: No, the median of $19$ things is the $\frac {19+1}2=10$th term.  You have $9$ below, the median itself, and $9$ above.

Comment: yeah definitely ,